# Intersection of $(n-1)$-rectifiable set with hyperplane

Tags: measure-theory, riemannian-geometry, lipschitz-functions, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose $E$ is a $(n-1)$-rectifiable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means $E$ is a set that has Hausdorff dimension $n-1$ and $H^{n-1} (E) < \infty$ and there is a countable family of Lipschitz maps $f_i: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the union of their image covers $H^{n-1} $- almost all $E$. Given a hyper-hyperplane $H_0$ and consider the collection of planes $C = \{H_0+v: v \bot H_0 \}$. Is for $L^{n-2}$- a.e. hyperplanes $H \in C$, $H\cap E$ necessarily a rectifiable curve? I think this intuitionally makes sense to me but I'm not sure if it is a valid statement.

Comment: Mattila's book "Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces" should be helpful. I think the statement is "true", but you have to avoid some configurations; for example, $E$ is a portion of a hyperplane and $H_0$ is parallel. On the other hand, is hyper-hyperplane a typo? Shouldn't be the measure $L^1$ instead of $L^{n-2}$?